# How to disable sending an email after a recurring contribution?

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions

The email sent isn't very clear, and offer an option to change the amount and instalment details

"You can update recurring contribution amount or change the number of installments details for this recurring contribution by visiting this web page."

And this change page has a warning message:

> Updates made using this form will change the recurring contribution
>   information stored in your CiviCRM database, but will NOT be sent to
>   the payment processor. You must enter the same changes using the
>   payment processor web site.

Rather than confusing users that have no clue what a CiviCRM database or a payment processor are nor where its website could be, I'd rather skip sending that email. Is there a way to disable that?

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought, but recurring givers may want to receive both the initial confirmation that their contribution was processed, and the monthly/quarterly/etc. notifications of additional payments being drawn.  A better option might be to remove the links to cancel/modify the recurring information from the relevant Smarty receipt templates.  That way they have their information but they're also not confused.